# Google Invite API(Beta) - how to get sender from invitation

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-app-invites

everyone! Is there a way to get sender information (name, picture etc.) from an invitation on receiver's side as it is visually represented on https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/ ?

On the other side is there a way for sender to know if his invitation is successfully received so, for example we can give sender some kind of a gift for that in our app?

Finally, is there a way for us to know if for example sender is putting fake email in invitation?

I found all this this very confusing and cannot find any specific answer on official site.

Answer (score 2):

AppInvite does not provide the sender name/picture in the invitation. Since the invitation is sent either by email or sms directly from the senders phone, you will get the sender information from the tool you use to read the email or sms.

There isn't any way for the sender to determine if an invite is received since there isn't any api or web page to get this data.

There isn't any way to put a "fake", i.e. different, email into an invitation, it's sent using the gmail account used when creating the invitation and can't be overridden by the user to some other account.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. As I said before, I was confused because of sample images used in official site (Food2You example), where you can see customized screen after deep linking on receiver side with invitation sender's name, but this is probably scr from google+ invite api or something else. I hope that futere versions of AppInvite will have mentioned feature related to a way for sender to determine if an invite is received.

Comment: @Jim, Just a question. Can't we use the deeplink information to gather sender data?